# VBA European and American number format

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to send data from EXCEL to a MySQL Database and I'm having issues when I run the Code from different computers. Different computers have different separator ("." or ",") configs and I am having some issues converting numbers.

I need to convert numbers from

"100.000,232" format to "100,000.232" format

I've been looking around and I can't seem to make it work with **NumberFormat** or **=SUBSTITUTE()** functions.

The code I have at the moment is the following

```
value = Int(Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).value) & "." & CLng(Split(CStr(Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).value), separator)(1))
```

where the ***separator*** is either `.` or `,`.
This code fails when I have "0,001" because it converts to "0.1" instead of "0.001"

Can you help me with this issue?

Best regards, Simon.

Comment: The easy way would be to change the delimiter in your windows... however, if send as value, there should be no problem... else change all cells to text and then use ctrl+h to delete . And afterwards replace , to .

Comment: I'm developing a code to work in different computers. The idea is not to change anything from the windows settings or user interface. I'd like to make the conversions and/or changes where the users eyes don't reach.

Comment: Have you tried simply `valueForMySQL = Str(Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).Value)`? `Str` will always use english decimal separator and MySQL will always need english decimal separator. So this should work independent from locale settings.

Comment: You are making the mistake of thinking that it matters to the computer whether a number uses a comma or a period as a decimal place. It doesn't unless you are using text representations of numbers to facilitate the transfer (e.g. passing a CSV). If an excel number is imported to an SQL database it doesn't matter what the regional settings are because one computer is writing the export and reading the import. It is only if one computer is writing an interim file like a CSV that is passed to another computer with different regional settings that there is a problem.

Comment: With that said, maybe look at the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx).

Comment: Axel Ritcher: I tried it and I lose the decimals. Example: "3,14" adds only "3" to the DB.
Jeeped: I'm not assuming anything. I am testing the code with different settings and computers and the values don't match. I add to the database using a simple SQL Query "INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Value) values (nId, nValues)" I even tried using (nId, 'nValues'). where my SQL Value is a Decimal(11,3) column and in my EXCEL is a 'Dim value as Double'

Comment: `Dim strValue as String : strValue = Str(Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).Value) : strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Value) values (" & nId & ", " & strValue & ")"` The `strSQL` is an concatenated string. So also the parts must be strings. If `Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).Value` is the double value `3,14` with german decimal comma, then `Str(Cells(MyLine, MyColumn).Value)` will be " 3.14" and this schould be right for the `strSQL`.

Comment: Do all the values being converted have three decimal places ??

Comment: Gary's Student: No. SQL Database only imports 3 of those, but the user may input more, it simple wont import more than 3 to the DB.
Axel Ritcher. After testing it your suggestion I get the same result. "3,14" is my cell value, then in my strV=str(cell.value) it stays on "3,14" and then on the strSQL = "query" & strV.... still stays on "3,14"

Comment: I've found a way to fix it. `Replace(Cells(Lines, cols).value, separator, ".")` where the separator is a manual config set by the user.

Comment: So it does send it as string or local settings do matter... but that doesn't make sense to me... values read binary (as everything is binary at the end) do not have chars (only a value)... using replace will send it as an string... so maybe the database itself only accept strings which automatically convert your values... still confusing to me...

Comment: However, you should post your solution as an answer and accept it. This way other ppl having the same issue get a fast solution :)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: He is concatenating a `SQL` `INSERT` statement and then probably he is executing this statement with MySQL. The concatenated `INSERT` statement is a string at all. So if you do `strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Value) values (" & 1 & ", " & 3.14 & ")"` the `3.14` will be implicit converted into a string. This is done with `CStr` by default. `CStr` uses locale settings. So with German Excel `3.14` will be converted to `"3,14"`. Using explicit conversion with `Str` can solve this problem since `Str` does *not* use locale settings.

Comment: Of course if the `3,14` is *not* a double value in German format but a string already, then even `Str` can't help. This is the case here, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to fix it. Replace(Cells(Lines, cols).value, separator, ".") where the 'separator' is a manual config set by the user. It can be "," or "."